# Show Solution to ODE is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $|y(x)|$ is bounded if $y'' + xg(x)y' + y = 0$ where $g(x) \ge 0 \; \forall x$.

I asked a few friends about it but they were stumped. I tried looking at $y'' + xy' + y = 0$ but I'm not even sure how to solve that ODE :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $y'$, we have
$$ y''y'+xg(x)(y')^2+yy'=0 $$
or
$$ \frac12((y')^2)'+xg(x)(y')^2+\frac12(y^2)'=0. $$
Now integrating both sides from 0 to $x$, we have
$$(y'(x))^2+2\int_0^xsg(s)(y'(s))^2ds+y^2(x)=(y'(0))^2+y^2(0). $$
Noting $\int_0^xsg(s)(y'(s))^2ds\ge 0$ for all $x$, so
$$ (y'(x))^2+y^2(x)\le(y'(0))^2+y^2(0). $$
Thus $|y(s)|$ is bounded.